# Custom RSpec Matcher That Takes A Block

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can a create the following RSpec matcher?

```
foo.bars.should incude_at_least_one {|bar| bar.id == 42 }
```

Let me know if I'm reinventing the wheel, but I'm also curious to know how to create a custom matcher that takes a block. Some of the built in matchers do it, so it's possible. I tried this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :incude_at_least_one do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.each do |item|
      return true if yield(item)
    end
    false
  end
end
```

I aslo tried passing `&block` at both leves. I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I started with the code from Neil Slater, and got it to work:

```
class IncludeAtLeastOne
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def matches?(actual)
    @actual = actual
    @actual.any? {|item| @block.call(item) }
  end

  def failure_message_for_should
    "expected #{@actual.inspect} to include at least one matching item, but it did not"
  end

  def failure_message_for_should_not
    "expected #{@actual.inspect} not to include at least one, but it did"
  end
end

def include_at_least_one(&block)
  IncludeAtLeastOne.new &block
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been discussion about adding such a matcher to rspec.  I am not sure about your block question but you could represent this test in the not as elegant looking:

```
foo.bars.any?{|bar| bar.id == 42}.should be_true
```

Probably easier than making a custom matcher and should be readable if your test is something like `it "should include at least one foo matching the id"`

Comment: Thanks.This is slightly prettier than the workaround I'm using. I still want to know how to create a matcher that takes a block.

Answer (score 0):

The RSpec DSL won't do it, but you could do something like this:

```
class IncludeAtLeastOne
  def matches?(target)
    @target = target
    @target.any? do |item|
      yield( item )
    end
  end

  def failure_message_for_should
    "expected #{@target.inspect} to include at least one thing"
  end

  def failure_message_for_should_not
    "expected #{@target.inspect} not to include at least one"
  end
end

def include_at_least_one
  IncludeAtLeastOne.new
end

describe "foos" do
  it "should contain something interesting" do
    [1,2,3].should include_at_least_one { |x| x == 1 }
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not quite work, but that's the correct way to do it. I will add an answer below with working code.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. I think the only difference between my answer and what you appear to want from your adjusted answer was explicit handling of the block as a variable? At least on my machine, my sample code ran successfully (including a yield to the block) when I tried it . . .